# Cron job cannot access database file I want updated

Tags: ruby, cron

I am trying to set up a cron job to, every 15 min, run a ruby script that lives inside the database folder of my ror website. The line I have in my crontab looks like this:

```
0,15,30,45 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'ruby /Users/arpitadey/rails_projects/sample_app/db/poller.rb'
```

poller.rb is supposed to collect some data remotely and then update a database file called sites.db with the new data. poller.rb and sites.db are in the same folder--so when i run poller.rb from the terminal, it finds sites.db and updates it just fine. But when poller.rb is run as a cron job, i get mail saying that there is no such table, sites. This error issues from the following line in poller.rb:

```
currentEnergy = db.query("SELECT energydata FROM sites")
```

The previous line in poller.rb,

```
db=SQLite3::Database.new("sites.db")
```

issues no error. I just learned about cron jobs today (since being kindly pointed toward them by some of you yesterday) and I think maybe since I have no background knowledge about general unix things (or computer science in general I should say), I can't understand a lot of posts on the subject. I am a lowly mechanical engineer and will not be able to understand answers involving unix background knowledge. I simply need to know how to alter my crontab so that cron will know where to find my database file, so that poller.rb will be able to update it. Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cron doesn't execute with your shell - so any enviornment variables would need to be set.  You can write a shell script that does the setting and then runs the ruby script.

Have the script look something like:

. $HOME/.profile

ruby /Users/arpitadey/rails_projects/sample_app/db/poller.r

And just have the cron job execute that script.

Ok, there may not be a .profile script  -  so create a file in your home directory with all your envirornment variables.

Call it poller.sh

type "env > poller.sh"

edit poller.sh

Make the first line #!/bin/sh

for each following line put export at the start of the line so it will look something like

```
#!/bin/sh
export GRAILS_HOME=/home/SillyUser/grails/
export PATH=/blah/blah/blah
...

At the bottom of the file:
ruby /Users/arpitadey/rails_projects/sample_app/db/poller.r
```

Comment: This is what I changed my crontab to finally: 0,15,30,45 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c '. $HOME/.profile; ruby /Users/arpitadey/rails_projects/sample_app/db/poller.rb'. But it's saying it doesn't know the location of /Users/arpitadey/.profile. So obviously I grossly misunderstood.

Comment: I would argue you didn't misunderstand but that I was unclear:). There may not be a .profile.  I'd create a shell script with the variables in it that launches the poller.r script.  Than have the cron job launch that shell script.

Comment: Is this more what you meant? 0,15,30,45 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /Users/arpitadey/rails_projects/sample_app; ruby /Users/arpitadey/rails_projects/sample_app/db/poller.rb' It still can't find my database, sites.db:(

Comment: o woops didn't see your previous comment. i will try that.

Comment: I am so so embarrassed. It's working now with the following line in my crontab: 0,15,30,45 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /Users/arpitadey/rails_projects/sample_app/db; ruby /Users/arpitadey/rails_projects/sample_app/db/poller.rb' I somehow left out the "/db" part of the path in the cd line when i tried this hours ago. But thank you for pointing me in the right direction with thinking of what comes after the "/bin/bash" as lines i'd write in my Terminal--which I now know is generically called a shell. I didn't even know what a shell was. But at least it's working! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your script:

```
Dir.chdir(File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)))
```

Comment: Right now I got my crontab line looking like this: 0,15,30,45 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /Users/arpitadey/rails_projects/sample_app; ruby /Users/arpitadey/rails_projects/sample_app/db/poller.rb'   Are you saying it should look like this? 0,15,30,45 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'Dir.chdir(File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)))
; ruby /Users/arpitadey/rails_projects/sample_app/db/poller.rb'